# Let tests in UFT automaticly run per ALM

Tags: hp-uft, hp-alm

I have a test-script written in UFT. How can I let this test run in ALM every morning at the same time. Like every morning at 10 AM automated?

Answer (score 1):

In ALM go to the Test Lab section in the Execution Flow tab, then right click a specific test and select *Test Run Schedule*.

[image: right-click test]

Select the *Time Dependency* tab and fill it out.

[image: schedule]