# UFT Scheduling a test by adding time dependency

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am working on scheduling an automation test every day. I have my test in the test lab and set a time dependency to the flow at 10.00 AM. I see that it is not working. Please answer the questions:

1. Could you please give me a possible solution to schedule the job?
2. Does HP ALM support scheduling?
3. If this doesn't work, do i have to create a batch file to execute
   the test in UFT and can you please give the code for creating a
   batch file to run the test with UFT?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you describe how you scheduled your tests?  Is it like that http://stackoverflow.com/q/32325953/2504101 ?

Answer (score 0):

I used HP ALM long back & feel that it is old school. You can use Jenkins for this. Other than scheduling an automated test at regular intervals, anyone can trigger the QTP/UFT scripts through a web interface. You can even pass parameters through the UI.

I trigger my application smoke test created using QTP through my mobile - sitting in star bucks and drinking my coffee!!

**Source:**

http://www.testautomationguru.com/executing-qtpuft-scripts-using-jenkins/

http://www.testautomationguru.com/qtpuft-jenkins-github-svn-integration/

http://www.testautomationguru.com/qtpuft-sending-out-email-with-test-results-using-jenkins/

Answer (score 0):

Try this link. This should get you going:
http://www.qtptutorial.net/qtpuft-running-your-scripts-at-scheduled-time-with-ease/